# Laravel 5 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::method()

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have projects which `hasMany` users, and users `belongsTo` a project.

I want to count the total amount of users a project has so I need to link them.

This way I'm getting a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user()` error.

What am I doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
private $project;

public function __construct(Project $project){

    $this->project = $project;

//        $this->project  = $project
//            ->with('user');
}


public function index(Project $project)
{

    $projects = $project->with('user')->get();

    $currenttime = Carbon::now();

//  return view('project.index', array('projects' => $projects, 'currenttime' => $currenttime));

    return view('user.index', compact('projects'));
}
```

}

**Model `user`:**

```
public function project(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id','id');
}
```

**Model `project`:**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id');
}
```

**HTML/Blade:**

```
 @if(isset($projects))

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-dynamic datatable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ trans('common.project') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('common.workers') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('common.completion_date') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('common.status')}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($projects as $project)
            <tr>
                <td>{!! link_to_route('project.edit', $project->name, [$project->id] )!!}</td>
                <td>{{ $project->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $project->completion_date }}</td>

                @if (($project->completed) == 1)
                    <td><span class="label label-success">{{ trans('common.completed') }}</span></td>
                @elseif(($project->completion_date) < $currenttime )
                    <td><span class="label label-danger">{{ trans('common.toolate') }}</span></td>
                @elseif(($project->active) == 0)
                    <td><span class="label label-default">{{ trans('common.inactive') }}</span></td>
                @else
                    <td><span class="label label-warning">{{ trans('common.inprogress') }}</span></td>
                @endif

            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>

    </table>
@endif
```

Comment: How are you calling this `$project->users;` ?

Comment: `public function index(Project $project)` from my model, if I'm right?

Comment: ok can you please try `dd($projects->users)`;

Comment: Both users/user will give an Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$users error, can't dd them. dd($projects) give the following results (see the other questions comment)

Comment: You are getting users collection in given output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78186/discussion-between-synyster-and-vps).

Comment: Your model relationship should be: belongsToMany

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide the method name that defines the relationship.I mean users not user

```
public function index(Project $project)
{
$projects = $project->with('users')->get();
$currenttime = Carbon::now();
//  return view('project.index', array('projects' => $projects, 'currenttime' => $currenttime));

return view('user.index', compact('projects'));
}
```

Comment: I got rid of the error, but when I dd($projects) it will show the projects but the relations are empty `( #relations: array:1 [▼
        "users" => Collection {#256 ▼
          #items: []
        }` whilst they are users linked to the projects in the database

Comment: your relation will not work because you are using user not users.try this

Comment: Just found out its a many to many relation and I have to use a pivot table, that is the problem.